# iterator for custom map operator-> overload using dummy reference

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a custom map-like container with (integer index,value) pairs. Here is my iterator implementation for it:

```
    // _v is a vector holding the data with next indices
    typedef int ind; // index type

    // T is the value type

    class iterator {
    private:
        idmap& owner;
        std::pair<ind, T&> _p;
    public:
        iterator(idmap& ic, ind x) : owner(ic), _p{x, *(T*)(&_p)} {}
        iterator& operator++() {
            _p.first = owner._v[_p.first]._next;
            return *this;
        }

        // the star* operator is straight forward
        std::pair<ind, T&> operator*() const { 
            return std::pair<ind, T&>(_p.first, owner._v[_p.first]._t);
        }
        
        // the -> operator is where the weirdness comes in
        std::pair<ind, T&>* operator->() const { 
            // placement new seems to reconstruct the pair without 
            // accessing the old dangling T& reference. Assignmet construction 
            // (_p = std::pair<>...) ended up corrupting data.
            new(&const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p) std::pair<ind, T&>(_p.first, owner._v[_p.first]._t);
            return &(const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p);
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) {
            return (&other.owner != &owner || other._p.first != _p.first);
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator& other) {
            return (&other.owner == &owner && other._p.first == _p.first);
        }
    };
```

In order to implement the arrow operator->, I need to return a pointer to pair type aka `std::pair<ind, T&>*` (pointer to live pair). To get this I have a local `std::pair<x, T&> _p` in the iterator that I copy-initialize to the current pair under iteration and return it in operator->.
To get around the issue of the uninitialized `T&` reference in `_p` I have initialized it to `*(T*)(&_p)` (`_p` is not a valid `T` object!) which looks super-sketch but I am pretty sure will never be accessed by the iterator before being updated in `operator->`. Do you see any problems with this, besides being just treacherous?

EDIT1:

The code works for iteration, however, the dangling reference causes issue as soon as the reference is accessed. For instance, assigning two fresh iterators to each other causes the copy constructor of std::pair to kick in and access the reference corrupting data.

EDIT2:

I ended up using `boost::variant<boost::blank, std::pair...>` to allow for an "uninitialized" pointer. The current code is:

```
    class iterator {
    private:
        idmap& owner;
        ind x;
        boost::variant<boost::blank, std::pair<ind, T&>> _p;
    public:
        iterator(idmap& ic, ind x) : owner(ic), x(x) {}
        iterator& operator++() {
            x = owner._v[x]._next;
            return *this;
        }

        const std::pair<ind, T&>& operator*() const {
            const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p = boost::blank();
            const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p = std::pair<ind, T&>(x, owner._v[x]._t);
            return boost::get<std::pair<ind, T&>>(const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p);
        }
        std::pair<ind, T&>* operator->() const {
            const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p = boost::blank();
            const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p = std::pair<ind, T&>(x, owner._v[x]._t);
            return &(boost::get<const std::pair<ind, T&>&>(const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p));
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) {
            return (&other.owner != &owner || other.x != x);
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator& other) {
            return (&other.owner == &owner && other.x == x);
        }
    };
```

This works well for iterating and the iterator is now copyable. The problem now is that:

```
for (const auto& x : idmp) {
   x.second = T();
}
```

compiles without error even though `const auto&` is supposed to capture a const `std::pair`. That is how `std::unordered_map` behaves in the same situation. Any ideas?

EDIT3 :

Even better idea is to use a byte storage and use placement new to keep the `std::pair` in the iterator, getting rid of the boost variant:

```
    class iterator {
    private:
        idmap& owner;
        ind x;
        static constexpr uint szp = sizeof(std::pair<ind, const T&>);
        static constexpr uint szpr = sizeof(std::pair<ind, const T&>);
        static constexpr uint sum_size = boost::static_unsigned_max<szp, szpr>::value + 1;
        uint8_t _p[sum_size];
    public:
        iterator(idmap& ic, ind x) : owner(ic), x(x) {}
        iterator& operator++() {
            x = owner._v[x]._next;
            return *this;
        }

        const std::pair<ind, T&>& operator*() const {
            new (const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p) std::pair<ind, T&>(x, owner._v[x]._t);
            return *((std::pair<ind, T&>*)const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p);
        }

        std::pair<ind, T&>* operator->() const {
            new (const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p) std::pair<ind, T&>(x, owner._v[x]._t);
            return (std::pair<ind, T&>*)const_cast<iterator*>(this)->_p;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) {
            return (&other.owner != &owner || other.x != x);
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator& other) {
            return (&other.owner == &owner && other.x == x);
        }
    };
```

The `for(const auto& x : idmp)` still does not behave like  `std::map` would, aka `x` becoming read-only.

Comment: What programming language do you think you should be targeting here? I doubt it's the [tag:r] language ...

Comment: fixed it. c++. Thanks.

Comment: this iterator is not copyable.  Perhaps `std::reference_wrapper`? `(T*)(&_p)` is UB technically (and incorrect cast approach also!).